# Trace/BPT trap: 5 error while trying to assign Apple_Boot type to external drive partition

Tags: terminal, macos-sierra, trace, partition, recovery

I am trying to create a bootable Mac Recovery partition on an external drive. I already cloned the recovery boot from my internal file system, to a partition I made on my external drive. I gave it enough space 5GB.

The problem that I am having now is, after I unmounted it, and entered

`sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk2s1 -settype Apple_Boot`

in terminal to change the type, it refuses to change the type. It just keeps spitting out this

`Trace/BPT trap: 5`

error and I have no idea what thats about.

Like I mentioned, the drive is unmounted. Also, I checked that I have permission to set the type to `Apple_Boot` . Although, I guess something might be changing it back or something. I don't really know.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? It would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was a hardware issue. I used a flash drive in place of an external and it worked fine.